# Using a domain from one provider and hosting from anotther

Tags: domains, web-hosting, dns, email, mail

I have a client who has a domain from company A but prefers hosting from company B. I know that this is possible, but the client also uses the mail services from company A using the domain that is parked there. I have little experience in this field, so will changing the DNS/NS to the hosting (B) affect their emails at company A?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and as per my experience you can do 2 things:

1. Use the Domain Provider NS and create cname/a records for your website like (www).example.com or (blog).example.com etc and use server's IP address for these and keep using mailbox provided from domain provider.
2. Forward your NS record to your hosting server and then manage NS records from there. It'll result in inaccessibility of the emails provided by domain provider, but you can create new email accounts on server itself and start using it from there. (Take backup of your emails on domain provider or see if they can be exported in a format supported by your server's email client)